# Is there a way to generate a graph based on date datatype from excel in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, matplotlib

I want to create an application that can import an excel file into the application, and generate or display a graph based on a timeseries data, eg: date, year, month, etc.

[example of the graph based on month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74F2n.jpg)

I have already create a browse function to import the excel file using tkinter.

[my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCBmO.jpg)

How do I generate the graph based on the available data in the imported excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `pandas` and the `datetime` library will solve your problem here.

You can read in your excel file using the pandas module as explained in the other answer.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("yourExcelFileName.xlsx")
```

You will then have to do some formatting to extract the date information you want. Your example shows counts by month so let's use that as an example here.

```
# first make sure the column is a datetime object
df['RegistrationDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RegistrationDate'])

# Next create a month column
df['RegistrationMonth'] = df['RegistrationDate'].apply(lambda x: x.to_pydatetime().strftime("%B"))

# you could use .strftime("%b") for short month name, e.g. Nov rather than November

# Do a groupby to count by that month
grouped_table = df[['RegistrationMonth', 'Id']].groupby('RegistrationMonth').agg('count')

#finally plot the results:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(grouped_table.index, grouped_table['Id'])
plt.show()
```

If you've never used pandas or matplotlib before you are likely to end up with many follow on questions, but there are many previously asked questions here to help you get on your way.

Comment: I get this error:
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'month_name'

Comment: Sorry I hadn't realised that pandas uses Timestamp not standard python Datetime. I have adjusted the line that extracts the month to: `df['RegistrationMonth'] = df['RegistrationDate'].apply(lambda x: x.to_pydatetime().month_name())` maybe you can try that?

Comment: Btw here is a reference to the Timestamp object in pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html

Comment: I got another error: ```AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'month_name'```

Comment: I changed the ```month_name``` to ```month``` and it says that ```TypeError: 'int' object is not callable```

Comment: Ok, sorry my answer has not been the most direct route to a solution!

Comment: The error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` means that `month` is an object of type `int`. It's not a function so you can't call it (i.e. `month()` doesn't work)

I have updated the lambda function in my answer to: `x.to_pydatetime().strftime("%B")`. Try this.

Comment: I got another error: ```NameError: name 'groupby' is not defined``` :(

Comment: I used `groupby` instead of `grouped_table` in the plotting step. I have updated the answer, try again?

Comment: I changed it like what you said and add ```plt.show()``` so that it can show as a figure, and finally it worked! Thanks! Btw can i know what is the purposed of adding ```index``` at ```grouped_table.index``` ? what is the function of ```index``` ? Thank you in advanced! :)

Comment: We got there in the end! The `grouped_table.index` is needed as the `bar` method requires x position as the first argument and height as the second. In our case the x position can be taken from the index, since the index is the default enumeration. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using pandas for this. You can read an excel with pandas an also create a histogram with this simple approach:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("yourExcelFileName.xlsx")
ax = df.plot.hist(bins=12)
```

The latter code will take each column and plot the data inside of it as a bar. So, in case you don't need some columns from your excel file, you can drop them or just create a new data frame from those columns. You can find more information in pandas official documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html